# Aligning Hair with Complex Surface Features

Tags: modeling, modifiers, hair

I'm attempting to create an anatomically correct model of the human body down to the 0.1mm scale. As part of this, I need to align the hair strands with features on the skin. An examination of figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Romt.png) or one's own skin will show that hairs occur on pores which are visible as point depressions, with creases running between them (most visible on the back of the hand). Given that the model aims to be as parametric as possible, what is the best way to achieve such a coupling?

My attempts thus far rely on creating a hair net that hugs the skin using the 'Surface Deform' modifier. The vertices represent the pores, and the edges the creases between them. Since hair can be set to emit from vertices, coupling is achieved. However this method lacks an efficient way of applying this data to the skin displacement --- dynamic paint seems ill-suited to the problem. Furthermore, it is probably the case that multiple hairs are emitted per-vertex, which is an issue for animation.

[image: Diagram of hair follicle courtesy Wikimedia Commons]

**Edit 22/09/2021**: This question has been in hibernation for almost a year. In that time, Blender has progressed significantly - warranting a re-evaluation of the possibilities especially w.r.t. geometry nodes as a solution. I apologize if the bump is inappropriate despite this.